# Schengen Visa: Tourist or Visitor

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas, tourism

I am a Non-Euro citizen, traveling to France and Switzerland for Tourism for 15 days.
My entry and exit flights are from France.
My stay in **France** is for **6** days
And stay in **Switzerland** is for **9** days.

I am staying in **Switzerland** at **Airbnb**.
In **France** I am staying at the **house** of  a non-european **friend** who lives there for his employment in the embassy of my parent country.

I have applied for **Tourist Visa from Switzerland**, in my application and covering letter I have mentioned the purpose of trip as Tourism and my Itinerary reflects the same, I have also attached a letter of Invitation from my friend in France stating that **during my transit** to Switzerland I will be staying in France at his place.  But during submission of my application the VFS global employee tells me that, as I have attached a letter of Invitation from my friend in France, the embassy of Switzerland may simply reject my application stating that I should have applied for Visa from France instead of Switzerland as my intent of visit will change from tourism to Visitor if I stay at my friend's place. Is it true?

Comment: If you're just staying at his place, then why is he inviting you? You said you have a *letter of invitation* from your friend in France, but you're actually planning to go to Switzerland, you don't see a problem with this story?

Comment: @littleadv What's the problem with his story? When I go as a tourist to some place, if my friend is in that city, I usually prefer to stay with friend rather than a hotel. Why is that an issue?

Comment: It's an issue when you're not actually being a tourist, but rather a guest. Your friend invited you, so you're going. I agree with the assessment of the VFS Global employee, it sounds like you're visiting your friend and going to Switzerland by the way. Your main trigger for your visit is your friend in France, so you should apply for a visa from France.

Comment: The rules are clear. Since you will spend more time in Switzerland than in France, the application should be made at the Swiss consulate (as you have done). [European Commission: Where and how to apply for a Schengen visa](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/visa-policy/where-and-how-apply-schengen-visa_en): *... **or** – if you intend to visit more than one Schengen State, the Consulate of the country **where you will spend the longest period**.*

Comment: @littleadv The main purpose of this rule is to insure that the applications are **evenly** spread out between the consulates. The situation might be different if the OP was attending a 2 day conference in France before or after the 9 days in Switzerland, but not because the OP stayed with a friend on the way to and from Switzerland.

Comment: @MarkJohnson It's not clear at all. It's quite sloppy on the part of the EU Commission to write that when that's emphatically not what's in the Visa Code (article 5). It says "main destination of the visit(s) in terms of the length of stay, counted in days, **or the purpose of stay**" for a reason, if it was merely about counting days, it would just say that.

Comment: You're also arguably wrong about the purpose of this rule but I am afraid that discussing that will give you a pretext to weasel out of admitting you were categorically and unambiguously wrong about the rule itself.

Comment: You have a friend which work on the embassy? I would ask him (not a website). He can get good information: family members "of embassies" do often what you are doing (+ they known how things works).

Comment: @Relaxed The 3 samples given in the *Visa Code Handbook I*, Part II 1.1.2 make it clear that the duration is the main priority: *Example: A Moroccan national wishes to travel to France for a family visit (20 days) and has additionally organised a meeting with a business partner in Belgium (two days). He will arrive at and leave from Amsterdam (Netherlands).
 **The main purpose of the trip is the family event, and thus the French consulate should deal with the application.***

Comment: @MarkJohnson Doesn't change a thing but before we discuss an example you do not seem to understand (note how the reasoning mentions the purpose and **not** the duration?), will you recognise that it was wrong to imply the rule was only about the number of days? Why do you suppose it mentions “the purpose of stay”?

Comment: I have a small additional query here, is there any other way through which I could have proven my stay at my friend's place without a letter of Invitation, at first place?

Comment: @VivekSaxena 'an invitation from the host if staying with one' is listed as a document relating to accommodation 'for journeys undertaken for the purposes of tourism or for private reasons'. It's perfectly fine as is for your situation.

Comment: @Relaxed You are the one using the word 'only', I used 'mainly'. Your deliberate misquoting/rewording is inappropriate.

Comment: @MarkJohnson The starting point of this whole discussion is your own comment: *The rules are clear. Since you will spend more time in Switzerland than in France, the application should be made at the Swiss consulate (as you have done).* It doesn't say “mainly“ and you go on to give a quote that implies it's the only rule so I don't think I am misquoting anything. In actual fact, the rules are anything but clear and you forget to mention the only one that's relevant.

Comment: Now, do you agree that the actual rule is “main destination of the visit(s) in terms of the length of stay, counted in days, or the purpose of stay”? Why do you suppose it says “purpose of stay”?

Comment: @Relaxed Because it is a disjunctive condition where the first, in this case, has been fulfilled so those after the first 'or' do not need to be taken into further consideration.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That makes no sense, that's not what “or” means, you are just making stuff up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tourist and visitor visas are one and the same thing. You have to tell the consulate about the purpose of your trip and there are some guidelines about the type of documentation expected based on that but no hard and fast rules or distinct categories of visas.

What I think is going on here is a little different. With all the details you provided (invitation letter, friend in France), it looks like the trip wouldn't happen if you weren't going to France to see your friend. It can therefore be considered the main destination and you would then have to apply to the French rather than the Swiss consulate. Staying a little longer in Switzerland blurs the picture a little bit but it is true that a consulate can decline to process an application if they think you should have applied to another consulate.

Note that if the Swiss consulate would decline to process the application on that basis, it would not be a refusal and they should refund the visa applifcation fee (VFS global may try to keep their fee but I am not sure whether that's legal). You would however need to reapply to the French consulate and potentially lose a lot of time waiting for another appointment (or even be forced to cancel the trip if there is no time) so that's not completely hassle-free for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Fingers crossed. Actually I have very little time from the date of departure in next 2 weeks. :)

Comment: I have a small additional query here, is there any other way through which I could have proven my stay at my friend's place without a letter of Invitation, at first place?

Comment: @VivekSaxena Providing a letter of invitation was the right choice. That's what it's for. Since you are staying with them for almost half the duration of the trip (give or take a day), you cannot avoid the suggestion that it's the main purpose. The only way to avoid that would be to stay much longer in Switzerland, visit several countries, book a hotel in France, or otherwise change the itinerary. Merely fiddling with the documentation wouldn't have helped you (and could hurt you).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious time

Comment: @VivekSaxena VFS has to courier the application to the consulate, where the consulate may decide that the application is inadmissible.  I'm afraid that the fact that they have sent the application to the consulate doesn't mean that it's been deemed acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The application is made already, there is not much you can do apart from wait now anyway...  Sometimes visa centre staff don't really know the rules themselves and ask you to sign waivers or declarations saying that they are not responsible for the outcome. Ultimately they all serve to make sure they get paid even if the visa is not issued.

Without having seen the letter from your friend I am not sure why they might decide that France is the main destination, unless there was something in the content that got their attention.  You may equally be visiting your friend because you will be nearby for your holiday, just as much as you are only going on holiday off the back of visiting your friend, which are both broadly speaking the same purpose anyway. Perhaps if it is not accepted maybe share a bit more detail on the contents of the letter?

Of course if the Swiss consulate returns the application and then you apply to France, they could possibly also say, "Switzerland is the main destination".

One thing I would point out is that if you applied to France on the basis of staying with a friend, you would normally need a "[Attestation d'accueil](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2191)" from the local town hall in France.  This would not necessarily have been required for the application you have made to the Swiss consulate, different consulates can ask for slightly different documents.

Anyway, you have submitted and it is no longer in your hands, my advice is try not to worry about it... visa centre staff regularly scare applicants when they caveat their own uncertainty, and then the visa is processed without a hitch... this happens surprisingly often!

Good luck, I hope you are issued your visa :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious time